# OpenBLAS preset in the DL4J library for Android

Tags: java, android, openblas, dl4j, nd4j

I am trying to run **OpenBLAS** preset in the **DL4J library** but i am having a problem in `SetNumThreads.allocate()`

the library implementation in `build.gradle`:

```
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-arm"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-arm64"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-x86"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-x86_64"
```

and    `multiDexEnabled true`.

When i run this method in my android app:

```
INDArray i = Nd4j.zeros(height, width, channels);
```

I get this error message:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.bytedeco.openblas.presets.openblas_nolapack$SetNumThreads.allocate() 
(tried Java_org_bytedeco_openblas_presets_openblas_1nolapack_00024SetNumThreads_allocate and Java_org_bytedeco_openblas_presets_openblas_1nolapack_00024SetNumThreads_allocate__)
```

Comment: Confirm that you have `multiDexEnabled true` per instructions: https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-android

Comment: @MorrisonChang I did, and did confirm that it does adb install-multiple with several slices... but still the same error. Any other idea?

Comment: Is your problem solved yet? I am facing the same problem with `Nd4j.create()`.